# In VSCode task, how can I indicate an env var from my machine in options.env?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I have a task configured like so:

```
{
    "label": "Uvicorn toto-scrapper",
    "type": "shell",
    "command": "cd ./app/toto-scrapper && python main.py #uvicorn main:app",
    "problemMatcher": [],
    "options": {
        "env": {
            "APP_TITLE": "toto-scrapper",
            "VERSION": "work-in-progress",
            "LOG_LEVEL": "DEBUG",
            "TOTO_URL": "XXX",
            "TOTO_USER": "$XXX_TOTO_LOGIN",
            "TOTO_PASSWORD": "$XXX_TOTO_PWD",
            "TOTO_REALM": "XXX",
            "TOTO_PLATFORM": "2"
        }
    }
}
```

This task is supposed to be shared by developers. Consequently, I would like to indicate, for the variables TOTO_USER and TOTO_PASSWORD, to VSCode to use the already defined environment variables of the computer, XXX_TOTO_LOGIN and XXX_TOTO_PWD.

However, doing as showed above provides the values "$XXX_TOTO_LOGIN" and "$XXX_TOTO_PWD" for the variables accessed in the code like so:

```
print(f'{os.environ["TOTO_USER"]}, {os.environ["TOTO_PASSWORD"]}')
```

Is it possible to tell VSCode task to use a env var of the machine as a variable in options.env of a task ? If yes, how ?

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_environment-variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As rioV8 said in the comments:

- Refer to https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_environment-variables

Example:

```
    "options": {
        "env": {
            "SOME_VALUE": "${env:SOME_VALUE_FROM_MACHINE_ENV_VAR}",
        }
```